# Using node-fetch to embed DnD spells from api

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-fetch

I'm wanting to be able to embed specific DnD spells taken from the [5e Api](https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/) using a Discord bot. I can log all of the spells to the console using node-fetch but completely unsure of the next step in grabbing user input, mapping it to the correct spell and then embeding it.

What the console log looks like after running the command:

```
{
  count: 319,
  results: [
    {
      index: 'acid-arrow',
      name: 'Acid Arrow',
      url: '/api/spells/acid-arrow'
    },
(*Continuing on for all of the spells*)
```

I essentially would like the command to be:

*!s acid arrow* (for example)

Which then returns:

[Discord embed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DruDn.png)

Here is the code from the command I have so far:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'spells',
    aliases: ['s'],
    category: 'dnd',
    description: 'Returns spell info',
    usage: '!s <spell name>',
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json));

        **?????????????;**

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle()
            .addField('Description:')
            .addField('At higher levels:')
            .addField('Range:')
            .addField('Components:')
            .addField('Materials needed:')
            .addField('Is it a ritual:')
            .addField('Needs concentration:')
            .addField('Level:')
            .addField('Casting time:');

        message.channel.send({ embed });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off, you don't need to use `.then()` twice after fetching the `spells`.

According to what I can see when I visit https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/ every `spell` has an `index` which can be used to look up a `spell` and is usually the `spell` `name` join using a `-` so if you grab the user's input, let's say `!s acid arrow` you can do

```js
fetch(`https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/${args.join('-')}`)
```

Which will fetch https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/acid-arrow. This will help avoid having you look for the `spell`.

Then you can use `.then()` to use the `spell` info and pass it to the `embed`.

So your solution would be:

```js
fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/')
    .then(res => {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(res.name)
            .addField('Description:', res.desc.join('\n'))
            .addField('At higher levels:', res.higher_level.join('\n'))
            .addField('Range:', res.range)
            .addField('Components:', res.components.join('\n'))
            .addField('Materials needed:', res.material)
            .addField('Is it a ritual:', res.ritual ? 'Yes' : 'No')
            .addField('Needs concentration:', res.concentration ? 'Yes' : 'No')
            .addField('Level:', res.level)
            .addField('Casting time:', res.casting_time);

        message.channel.send(embed);
    })
    .catch(err => message.reply('that spell does not exist!'));
```

Comment: I’m not in a position to go and try it right away but I just want to say thanks for responding so thoroughly and quickly!